# can not find schema info when configuration quartz.net

Tags: c#

When i add this code to app.config in Windows service program:

```
     <quartz>
        <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ExampleDefaultQuartzScheduler"/>
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"/>
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10"/>
        <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2"/>
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000"/>
        <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz"/>
    </quartz>
```

it tips:

```
  Could not find schema information for the element `key`.  
  Could not find schema information for the attribute `quartz`.  
  Could not find schema information for the element `value`.
```

I am sure i have using `job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd` file in background.

And predefine the quartz:

```
<configSections>
        <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>     
</configSections>
```

Where is the problem?And where to find the schema info?

And when is the label `<quartz>` namespace?

Where should i find the xsd file of quartz.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal reason is your config file lack of schema file like ***.xsd** in:**..\Microsoft Visual Studio\Xml\Schemas** folder.

You can omit these tips,**it could not affect your program running**.

Or you can write the xsd schema file by yourself.